# Virtualbox installation using sudo apt install giving error for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, updates, virtualbox

On using command
`sudo apt install virtualbox`

it's giving Output as

```
  virtualbox-6.1 6.1.32-149290~Ubuntu~eoan
  virtualbox-6.0 6.0.24-139119~Ubuntu~eoan
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'virtualbox' has no installation candidate
```

I have tried using
`sudo apt install virtualbox-6.1 6.1.32-149290~Ubuntu~eoan`
but getting this
`E: Unable to locate package 6.1.32-149290~Ubuntu~eoan`
/etc/apt/sources.list
contains

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
```

even tried sudo apt update and used sudo apt install virtualbox-6.1 but getting this
`W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3`

for apt install virtualbox-6.1

```
 virtualbox-6.1 : Depends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please suggest how can i install virtualbox through sudo apt install?
Thanks.

Comment: The references to Eoan says that you have some repositories for 19.10 still active. You may want to double check your sources and then install with `sudo apt install VirtualBox` 

Comment: Hi @matigo, Thanks for replying..can u tell me which command will be useful for the following scenario? I am new to linux.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there was error in /etc/apt/sources.list and there were duplicate entries also which i removed from software & updates as a result sudo apt update started working followed by that sudo apt install virtualbox also started wokring.